# pcl-ros datatype conversion

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to convert the Voxel grid filter to the ROS ecosystem. Instead of using 'pcl::PCLPointCloud2' data structure as given in the example code, I'm trying to use 'pcl::PointCloud' data structure (as in Euclidean Cluster Extraction). However, I'm not able to find the API that converts pcl::PointCloud to ROS message type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190988/pcl-ros-datatype-conversion/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will find that the VoxelGrid filter is already available as a nodelt (http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Filters#VoxelGrid, http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/VoxelGrid%20filtering).

Read the [ROS/PCL overview](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview) for a description on how to subscribe, publish, and convert between the different datatypes.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0